# How to write to a specific line in a text file using ruby

Tags: ruby, file, text, file-writing

Alright, so I have a ruby file and a text file. The code is like this:

```
fname = "sample.txt"
somefile = File.open(fname, "a")
somefile.puts "Hello file!"
somefile.close
```

so what i'd like to do is instead of adding it to the end of the file, add it to a specific line. The text file looks like this:

```
names
kyle
andrew
joshua
devon
```

so what I'd like to be able to do it to insert text between "kyle" and "andrew", with each on a seperate line. Please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to insert a string into a textfile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139058/how-to-insert-a-string-into-a-textfile)

Answer (score 2):

Random access is for read-only purpose, if you want to write a random line:

- read the file
- find the line you want to append text
- append and write a new file

```ruby
require 'stringio'
tmp = StringIO.open
origin.each do |line|
  tmp<<line
  if line == 'kyle'
    tmp << 'new line !'
  end
end
tmp.seek 0
File.open(fname, "wb").write tmp.read
```

the file then looks like:

```html
names
kyle
new line !
andrew
joshua
devon
```